# Scala :: Read multiple parquet files with different schema information

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, parquet

I have a requirement where I have to read parquet files in different directories in HDFS. The directories are broken down by client and each client has a different schema (naming convention).

I am using scala to read these files into a dataframe. Is there a way where I can dynamically change the input field names by using client name as an input parameter. I have close to 30 clients to read from.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can first construct the schema programmatically using `StructType` 
class https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema , then do something like

```
spark.read.schema(myGeneratedSchema).parquet(path)
```